# Django Rest-Framework Serializer ignoring model ID

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update a model using Django rest-framework.

serializers.py

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):       
    class Meta:                                                      
        model = MatchModel                                           
        fields = ("id", "player_1", "player_2")
```

models.py

```
class MatchModel(models.Model):                                 
    player_1 = models.CharField(max_length=256)                 
    player_2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

views.py

```
class MatchesViewSet(APIView):  

    ...  

    def put(self, request, format=None):                                     
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=json.loads(request.body))    
        if serializer.is_valid():                                            
            serializer.save()                                                
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

The request is generated like this:

```
match = {                                                                         
        "id": 1,                                                                  
        "player_1": "updatedP1",                                                  
        "player_2": "updatedP2",                                                  
        }                                                                         
r = self.c.put("/api/matches", json.dumps(match), content_type="application/json")
```

But the thing keeps adding a new match, instead of updating the existing match with id=1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `serializer.save()` to update an existing instance, you need to pass it when instantiating the serializer class, e.g.:

```
def put(self, request, format=None):
    data = json.loads(request.body)        
    instance = get_object_or_404(MatchModel, pk=data["id"])
    serializer = self.serializer_class(instance, data=data)
    ...
```

Check [Saving instances](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) for more details.

PS, you may also want to use separate resources for individual matches (e.g. `/api/matches/1`) instead of the single `/api/matches`.